# Can't get form data from site to save in database Django MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using Django with MySQL database. Everything is working, but the data I input will not save to the database.

This is my HTML:

```
 <form class="space-y-8 divide-y divide-gray-200 m-2">
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="space-y-8 divide-y divide-gray-200">
        <div class="pt-8">
            <div>
                <h3 class="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">
                    Project Information
                </h3>

            </div>
            <div class="mt-6 grid grid-cols-1 gap-y-6 gap-x-4 sm:grid-cols-6">
                <div class="sm:col-span-3">
                    <label for="project-name" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                        Project Name
                    </label>
                    <div class="mt-1">
                        <input type="text" name="project-name" id="project-name"
                            class="shadow-sm focus:ring-gray-500 focus:border-gray-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sm:col-span-3">
                    <label for="project-location" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                        Project Location
                    </label>
                    <div class="mt-1">
                        <input type="text" name="project-location" id="project-location"
                            class="shadow-sm focus:ring-gray-500 focus:border-gray-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-6 grid grid-cols-1 gap-y-6 gap-x-4 sm:grid-cols-6">
                <div class="sm:col-span-3">
                    <label for="project-operator" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                        Operator
                    </label>
                    <div class="mt-1">
                        <input type="text" name="project-operator" id="project-operator"
                            class="shadow-sm focus:ring-gray-500 focus:border-gray-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sm:col-span-3">
                    <label for="project-start-date" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                        Start Date
                    </label>
                    <div class="mt-1">
                        <input type="text" name="project-start-date" id="project-start-date"
                            class="shadow-sm focus:ring-gray-500 focus:border-gray-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pt-5">
            <div class="flex justify-end">
                <button type="submit"
                    class="ml-3 inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-gray-600 hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-gray-500">
                    Save
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my views.py

```
def project(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            all_items = Project.objects.all
            return render(request, 'project.html', {'all_items': all_items})

    all_items = Project.objects.all
    return render(request, 'project.html', {'all_items': all_items})
```

This is my forms.py:

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['project_name', 'project_location',
                  'operator', 'date_started']
```

This is my models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    project_location = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    operator = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date_started = models.DateField()
```

I am not getting any errors, but the data I save is not saved in the database. Can anyone see what I need to fix?

Comment: Where is your form in your html file ?

Comment: What happens if the form is not valid?

Comment: Nothing happens if the form is not valid.

Comment: If you are using django form, then you should use that in your template

Comment: @Prakhar I am not sure what you mean. Can you please explain?

Comment: Will write an answer wait

Comment: @LoudEye try out the solution, thats the django way of handling forms. If you want to use css. Check out for `crispy_form` .

Comment: @Prakhar 
I replaced all of my code with yours and I get the same result. The page does not show any errors, but the data does not go into the data base.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236807/discussion-between-prakhar-and-loudeye).

Comment: @Prakhar Could it be because I am using MySQL instead of SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

In your `view` which directs you to `html` page :

```
def project(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
      form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         form.save()
      else:
         print("Invalid input from user") # for debugging only, handle according to your need

    form = ProjectForm()
    all_items = Project.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'project.html', {'form': form, 'all_items':all_items})
```

In your `html`

```
<form action="{% url 'url_name_for_your_project_view' %}" method="POST">

{% csrf_token %}

{{ form }}

<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```